# Actual days taken from Maundy Thursday to Crucifixion

Tags: gospels, chronology, passion-of-jesus, geography

What we currently know is that the Jesus was taken custody after the last supper (Maundy Thursday) and crucified on Good Friday, the day after the last supper.

My Question is, can this be true?

I mean can they do everything what it is said they did to Jesus in less than 24 hours before they crucified him.

The list of activities they did to him:

1. start the trial
2. beat him nearly to the death
3. Tried by Pontius Pilate
4. Take him to Herod Antipas, and the list goes on

In google maps, the distance between Judea to Galilee is nearly more than 100 kms.

Check this link : [How long would it take to walk from Judea to Galilee?](https://www.quora.com/How-long-would-it-take-to-walk-from-Judea-to-Galilee)

**Note :** *I can understand that we are celebrating these incidents in consecutive days, but what would have happened in reality.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the events are reported to have taken place in Jerusalem - there is no need incorporate a journey from Galilee to Jerusalem in to the required timetable. Perhaps your confusion is in regard to the involvement of Herod Antipas, the tetrarch of Galilee whom Jesus was sent to; however:

> <sup>6</sup> On hearing this, Pilate asked if the man was a Galilean. <sup>7</sup> When he learned that Jesus was under Herod’s jurisdiction, he sent him to Herod, **who was also in Jerusalem at that time.** - [Luke 23](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2023&version=NIV):6-7 NIV [*emphasis added*]

Given the close proximity of the settings for the various events you've listed, there is no particular problem with the reported timeline.

Comment: Noted. Do you think they calculated the time as 24 hours as how we do it right now for a day? Coz I've heard that they have different measurement for the time in ancient Jerusalem. (No resources). I'm trying to match my faith  into reality at least up to some point.

Comment: @Thush-Fdo Same 24-hour times, but the Jews started their day at sundown (6pm) while the Greeks started at midnight.